# Chartjs (Non Vue) Not Rendering Graph Chart inside V-if/V-show

Tags: vuejs2, chart.js

I have a page containing multiple charts drawn using chartjs. The problem is that when I am drawing the chart inside a div while it is hidden by v-if or v-show, the chart will not appear when the condition changes and the hidden div appears. Is there some way to do it. I have tried using `update` but that doesn't work. Chart only appears when it created at time when the concerned div is not hidden.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue with vue-chartjs as well. What worked for me is to use v-show instead.

The block I had previously in v-else, I know put in a new v-if block

```html
<div v-show="visualizationData">
    <myChart :chartData="visualizationData" :height="350" />
</div>

<div v-if="visualizationData === null">
    <div class="loadingIndicator">
      Loading...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest putting the chart's init function in the same method, or make a watcher method, like the one responsible for showing/hiding the element.

Like:

```
   <div v-if="visible">
     <div ref="chartContainer"></div>
   </div>

   .....
   methodThatChangesVisibility () {
     this.visible = true
     this.initChartMethod()
   }
```

When saying that you could set up a watcher, it's pretty much the same thing but independent from the visible gets set to true.

```
  watch: {
    visible: function (visible) {
      if (visible) this.initChartMethod()
    }
  }
```

Comment: But for that I will have to save the data some where that I got when the div is hidden and draw chart with that saved data. Isn't there a way when I get to draw the when div is hidden and it can appear when the div appears.

Comment: Check the DOM carefully, as I am pretty sure that the chart, in fact, IS rendering in the hidden div. However, it just has no dimension to calculate its size with, so it is rendered 0px in size. It is more common than not to save the data somewhere, whether that is on the HTML element itself or on the Vue component. I'd recommend using `v-show` as then you will know that any changes taking place or are on DOM but just not visible. If there is a hard constraint on adding chart data to the Vue component, try making a data attribute on the chart container like `data-chart="<SERIALIZED-DATA>"`

Answer (score 0):

`<div v-if="showChart">
    <div id="chartWrapper"></div>
</div>`

When boolean `showChart` is changed, entire outer div content is re-render or destroy. If destroyed `div` is render again, you need to initChart also when the time of `showChart` become `true`.